# is it possible to launch Anaconda Prompt from a .py file?

Tags: python, anaconda

is it possible to launch Anaconda Prompt from a .py file? I know it's possible from Jupyter notebooks but I couldn't find anything on this. Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use Anaconda Python to execute a .py file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39995380/how-to-use-anaconda-python-to-execute-a-py-file)

Comment: Nope, I'm looking for the other way around. From a .py file the command to launch Anaconda prompt